# Use SD Card while Pin 11 is being used for PWM

Tags: arduino-uno, pwm, sd-card

On Arduino Uno Rev3, I just ran the [`speaker_pcm`](https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/PCMAudio) demo that used TIMER1 and TIMER2 to generate a PWM wave. However, this means that the Pins 3, 9, 10 and 11 can not be used anymore; according to the documentation:

```
Takes over Timer 1 (16-bit) for the 8000 Hz timer. This breaks PWM
(analogWrite()) for Arduino pins 9 and 10. Takes Timer 2 (8-bit)
for the pulse width modulation, breaking PWM for pins 11 & 3.
```

I wanted to change the program such that the WAV data was read from a SD card. However, this is what [documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SDCardNotes) for `SD.h` library says:

```
The communication between the microcontroller and the SD card uses SPI,
which takes place on digital pins 11, 12, and 13 (on most Arduino boards)
```

This means both the `SD.h` and `speaker_pcm` want to use pin 11, and the requirement to use these pins is dictated by the hardware. I am guessing that this clash will create problems.

Is there any way I can make this work? Can I switch between SD card reading and Audio playing somehow (essentially multiplexing in software)? Or will this collision of pin usage not be a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program you link to does *not* take over pins 3, 9, 10 and 11, it
takes over Timer 1 and Timer 2, which are used to provide PWM capability
on those pins. This means you cannot do `analogWrite()` on those pins
anymore, but you still can use them for other purposes, including SPI
access to an SD card.

Note, however, this line of code:

```
int speakerPin = 11; // Can be either 3 or 11, two PWM outputs connected to Timer 2
```

This of course will conflict the SPI port using pin 11 as MOSI. You can
fix this conflict simply by setting `speakerPin` to 3 instead of 11.